# How to store the body of a JSTL custom tag into a variable?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I would like to create a custom JSP tag that can be used like this:

```
<mytags:myTag>
    <p>My content!</p>
</mytags:myTag>
```

In the tag, I would like to process the content of the body just like I would use any other attribute. So, the tag definition would look something like this - but the body would not be an attribute but *something* else.

**mytag.tag:**

```
<%@taglib prefix="mytags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/mytags" %>
<%@attribute name="body" required="true"%>

<div>
  <c:if test="${fn:contains(body, 'test')}">
    <p>Found test string<p>
  </c:if>
</div>
```

Obviously, something like `<jsp:doBody/>` or `<jsp:invoke fragment="body" />` will not help me. Also, it would seem a bit overly complicated to create a Java tag for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to capture the body content using the `<jsp:dobody>` action through its `var` attribute as demonstrated in [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-introduction-to-jsp-20s-tag-files/) article. The body content will be added as an attribute to the `pageContext` of your tag file and can be accessed through an expression.

**mytag.tag**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<jsp:doBody var="body"/>
<div>
    <c:if test="${ fn:contains(body, 'test') }">
        <p>Found test string</p>
    </c:if>
</div>
```